# Dynamically creating Objects at runtime with parameters DI vs Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, factory

I currently have a case where I have multiple customers who have variability of on what forms of notifications they want (ie email, fax, etc.). They could also want one or more than one. So I have created a factory with some basic Reflection that will dynamically create concrete classes depending on some parameters that get sent in through the customer profile. I'm curious is there a better way to do this using ASP.Net Core Dependency Injection? I have put in the factory code here to help folks understand of what I'm trying to do.

The customer profile will send in a string array of what services they have subscribed as a parameter to CreateInstances so only specific services would be dynamically created.

```
    public Dictionary<string, Type> Notifications;

    public NotificationFactory()
    {
        LoadTypes();
    }

    public IEnumerable<INotificationService> CreateInstances(params string[] namesOfServices)
    {
        var servicesToInstantiate = namesOfServices.ToList();
        List<INotificationService> result = new List<INotificationService>();

        foreach (var service in servicesToInstantiate)
        {
            Type serviceName = GetServiceNameToCreate(service.ToLower());
            if (serviceName != null)
            {
                result.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(serviceName) as INotificationService);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private Type GetServiceNameToCreate(string NotificationClassName)
    {
        return Notifications.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key.Contains(NotificationClassName)).Value;
    }

    protected virtual void LoadTypes()
    {
        Notifications = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(INotificationService).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface)
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Name.ToLower(), t => t);
    }
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This doesn't look too bad to me. I would consider putting all the service names in an enum, so that sending the service names in a list has less chance of finger trouble.

Comment: Thanks, Bertus! That is a good suggestion. But I wasn't sure if the DI engine in core would do a better job than me writing code in accomplishing my goal any thoughts?

Comment: DI requires being able to resolve instances based almost solely on the types in the constructor. If you have somewhat static logic, you can register your type with a factory method, However, in this case, that would be a bit difficult (though potentially not impossible) to achieve, since it's based on individual user preferences. It's probably better to just stick with your factory here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to take an arbitrary string and activate an instance the way you are doing it. The string should at least be white-listed. If a malicious user were able to tamper with the strings in the database, for example, they could choose what type to activate and potentially trigger unauthorized behavior or denial of service.

Instead, define a white list of types, and associate each type with a delegate that constructs the service you need.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<INotificationService>>
{
    { "EMAIL" : () => new EmailService() },
    { "PHONE" : () => new PhoneService() }
};
```

Then to get a service, call

```
if (!map.ContainsKey(serviceType)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(serviceType));
INotificationService service = map[serviceType]();
```

Or if you prefer:

```
Func<INotificationService> factory;
if (!map.TryGetValue(serviceType, out factory)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(serviceType));
INotificationService service = factory();
```

This way you are certain that the service type is one that you support, and you don't need to use any Reflection.

**If you need more extensibility**

If you want to be able to add more delivery methods without changing the code that populates `map`, you can of course populate the map from a configuration file. Although I'm left wondering how you could possibly implement a new delivery method without changing any code, and whether you have a bone fide NFR that requires you to be able to. Seems to me that new delivery methods don't get added very often and would be a big deal in other respects, so there is little point in saving yourself adding one line of code here.